# Does the Unknown have a name?

Tags: dark

In the Netflix subtitles and the fan wikis alike, Martha's son is referred to as Unknown (in the latter, the Unknown). However, one imagines that he has a name. For Martha not to have given him one would have been peculiar, given how much she seemed to care about him initially.

Does he have a name? Did Martha decide that it was not necessary? Or is his name simply Unknown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the beginning of episode 4 of season 3, Tronte (who turns out to be his son) has an encounter with the middle-aged version of Unknown outside the cave, and they exchange a few words, including these:

> Tronte: Do I know you?
>
> Unknown: I knew your mother. But that was long ago. You take after her. Your eyes.
>
> Tronte: Who are you?
>
> Unknown: I don't have a name. I was never given one.

So, it seems he has no name. (And we don't actually know if Martha raised him; given the way his whole life seems to revolve around time loops, it's possible his older selves came to the time right after he was born and took over parental duties themselves.)

Answer (score 1):

The Unknown himself states he has no name as he was never given one.

[Scene referenced.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gM4uiY32IvY)